# How to connect a 2-channel smart lights switch module?

Tags: wiring, lighting, smart-switch

I currently have this, with a "dumb" light switch connected (diagram included as the pic is a bit hard to see), it manages two ceiling lights:
[image: Diagram of current setp]
[image: Picture of current setup]

I want to disconnect that, and instead connect this smart switch module:
[image: Switch module I want to connect]

Important notes:

1. The new switch module does NOT use neutral.
2. The light switch module will not be connected to a physical "dumb light switch" (it will only be managed wirelessly).
3. Yes, I have turned off all power and double checked that it is off.

Any assistance in translating the old wiring to the new wiring would be much appreciated!

Let me know if I need to provide more information!

Comment: Where to the wires from 1,L & A go? Are they the Line (incoming supply) or Load (outgoing to the device being switched)?

Comment: @FreeMan they go to the wall, after that no clue where they go after that

Comment: Where in the world are you? I've never seen brown/grey/green-yellow. It does look like they're using the grey & green-yellow as L1 & L2, but that means somewhere at the other end there's something looking like a green-yellow earth wire that's hot!! [Usually you only get grey in a 4-wire cable, either as CPC or 3-phase.]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are in the UK based on the wire colors.  **If so** I believe (but am not sure) brown is the the line in.

I would:

- Disconnect a gray.  If brown is the line in then one of the lights should work and the other will not.
- Reconnect gray, disconnect the yellow, Same as the above.

Now if you find the brown is indeed the line input, connect it to "L" on your new device.
Then Yellow will be L1 and gray will be L2.